# Relation between the drawn node and the data node in Google chart/visualization

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using a Google Org Chart to show a site's page hierarchy.

I would like to colour the boxes based on some other factor - specifically the last update time of the page, but this question is more general.

I can load the data and draw the chart.

I've added an extra column to the data and drawn the chart.

Then `document.querySelectorAll('.google-visualization-orgchart-node');` gives me a list of the charts nodes.

But I can't work out how to join this back to the data. I could parse the text content, but this seems really messy/hacky.

**Is there no relation between the drawn node and the data node?**

I edited a Google sample to include an extra data column, and its on jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjmartin/4Xadv/

```
 <!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
        Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['orgchart'] });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function drawVisualization() {

            // Create and populate the data table.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable;

            data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
            data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
            data.addColumn('string' , 'extraData')

            var r;

            r = data.addRow(['Mike', null, 'The President','a']);
            data.addRow([{ v: 'Jim', f: 'Jim<br/><font color="red"><i>Vice President<i></font>' }, 'Mike', null,'b']);
            data.addRow(['Alice', 'Mike', null,'c']);
            data.addRow(['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge','d']);
            data.addRow(['Carol', 'Bob', null,'e']);


            // Create and draw the visualization.
            var v = document.getElementById('visualization');

            var orgChart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(v);


            orgChart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });

            var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.google-visualization-orgchart-node');
            for (var i = 0 ; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                console.log(nodes[i]);
            }


        }




        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've noticed that the chart select event can resolve the data row and column. But trying to debug through the obfuscation is giving me a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the [`style`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#customproperties) on the DataTable before drawing.

Comment: This will work for what I want this time. It's a shame there is no open method of resolving the relation or the ability to set more properties.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you feel is missing? We'd be happy to file bugs/prioritize.

Comment: Simply being able to tell the data row or cell that the drawn object represents. So once the chart is drawn, we could iterate document.querySelectorAll('CHART_DATA_ITEM_SELECTOR') and set or adjust the html|svg| properties.

Comment: Now I know about the set style method I can use that. But being able to set other properties could be useful. In the report I'm working on, I wanted to use the org chart and set the background colour based on the last updated date, so items that have not been updated recently show in red and get lighter as they are more current.